# уплачивать—уплатить

Tags: глаголы

Я не могу разобраться в разнице между ними.

Чем они отличаются от *платить* и *заплатить*?

Спасибо за любую помощь! )))

Comment: It seems,  "как эти разный, чем платить заплатить?" = "how do these differ from `платить заплатить`?"

Answer (score 4):

Are you asking about the difference between уплачивать and уплатить (which is a simple matter of aspects, as outlined above) or how both are different from another aspectual pair, платить/заплатить?

Regarding the latter: basically, уплатить refers to paying a set amount where trade is not (or not immediately) involved — usually taxes and similar fees. It's completely replaced with (за)платить in the vernacular, but уплатить is better formal style in applicable cases.

Comment: Thanks)) This was my question. 

To clarify what I wanted to say was (how are these different than)  и я написал (как эти разные, чем) как я могу это лучше сказать?? 

и кстати я совершил ошибку в первым сообщении ( лучше сказать (я не могу разбираться в разнице между ними—ними тут означает (заплатить и уплатить) мой компьютер просто изменил то слово (разбираться)

но извини меня за недоразумение, я толко русским языком занимаюсь 6 месяцев.

Comment: That's why English is better when asking specific questions. We all speak it :) Разобраться is more correct here than разбираться, by the way. The ambiguity was because of the impression that by между ними, you meant уплачивать and уплатить, which only differ in aspect.

Answer (score 3):

`Уплачивать` - глагол несовершенного вида, отвечает на вопрос "Что делать?"

`уплатить` - глагол совершенного вида, отвечает на вопрос "Что сделать?"

Глаголы **совершенного вида** указывают на **завершенность действия**, его результат, конец действия или его начало. В неопределенной форме они отвечают на вопрос **что сделать?**.
Например: `добежать, купить, зазвенеть, построить, запеть.`

> Прошедшее время: **что сделали?   что сделала?   что сделал?   что сделало?**
>
> `подбежали, увидела, нашел, взошло.`
>
> Будущее простое время: **что сделают?   что сделаю?   что сделает?и т.д.**
>
> `выйдут, куплю, доплывет, посчитаем.`

Обратите внимание на то, что у глаголов совершенного вида есть только две формы времени: прошедшее и будущее простое. Настоящее время отсутствует.

Глаголы **несовершенного вида** обозначают длительные или повторяющиеся действия, **без указания на их завершенность**.
В неопределенной форме они отвечают на вопрос **что делать?**.
Например: `петь, кипеть, бежать, мечтать, перечитывать, подпрыгивать`.

> Прошедшее время: **что делали?   что делал?   что делала?   что делало?**
>
> `бежали, прыгал, искала, заходило.`
>
> Настоящее время: **что делают?   что делаем?   что делает?и т.д.**
>   `загорают, строим, подтягивается, покупаю.`
>
> Будущее сложное время: **что будут делать?   что буду делать? и т.д.**
>   `будут прыгать, буду смеяться, будем слушать, будет танцевать.`

У глаголов несовершенного вида есть все три формы времени: **прошедшее, настоящее и будущее сложное.** 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I too am not sure I completely understand the question. If it is indeed about the difference between *заплатить* and *уплатить* then a good answer has already been given.

On a more general note, however, I would attract your attention to the fact that Russian  prefix derivation is insanely rich and productive. One must be careful to not be deceived by the apparent similarity of any two verbs which derive from the same base using different prefixes.

Where *заплатить* and *уплатить* may well be interchangeable in the majority of modern contexts (meaning *to pay up*), verbs formed by these two prefixes from other bases may well mean very different actions. See *заплыть*/*уплыть*, *зайти*/*уйти*, *закачать*/*укачать* to name but a very few.

I cannot overestimate the importance of understanding this aspect of Russian morphology when learning Russian as a foreign language. If English is your first language (which seems to be the case) try likening the Russian prefix derivation to the phenomenon of English phrasal verbs. Consider for example *put up*, *put off* and *put down* where different prepositions (which I daresay are analogous to Russian prefixes in this case) are appended to the same verb to produces three completely different meanings.

Comment: I know all about the aspectual pair sytem and prefixes. It's just in many cases dictionaries do not list any difference between a verb with у или за или итд and instead it just says they are exactly the same, which is of course impossible

thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical example of видовая пара.  Уплачивать is imperfective, уплатить is perfective.